# Google Sign-In for Websites, get user gender

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I am trying to build social logins for a client's site. I've done Facebook and I'm now trying to get Google to work.

I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
    $.getScript('//apis.google.com/js/platform.js', function(){
        gapi.load('auth2', function() {
            auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: '(MY_CLIENT_ID_HERE).apps.googleusercontent.com',
                scope: 'profile',
            });
            // basic listeners
        });
    });
});
```

I then check if the user is logged in and get the current user using `var googleUser = auth2.currentUser.get()`, and the user's basic profile info with `var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile()`. So far so good.

I can read basic profile values like:

```
console.log('First Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
console.log('Last Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
```

Great!

The one piece of information I get by default from Facebook that Google is not returning is the user's **gender**.

I've tried changing the `scope` in the object provided to `gapi.auth2.init` but could not find a way to retrieve the user's gender.

Can anyone show me a working example? Or point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like `GoogleUser` object doesn't support `gender` property. Only listed in OP plus `email_verified`.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Thanks for your input. I understand gender is not supported by the `scope` I'm using. I'd still like to know if there's a scope that would provide me with this piece of information, **or** how to query Google in order to get the user's gender, if it's publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

```
scopes: [
  'profile',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read',
],
```